# Find new range over linear transformation using change of variables technique

Tags: random-variables, transformation, conformal-geometry, change-of-variable

I have encountered some problems when solving problems of bivariate continuous random variables finding the new support. For example,

f(x,y) =\begin{cases}
2e^{-x-2y},  & \ {0<x<y<\infty} \\
0, & \text{else where}
\end{cases}

To find the distributions of U and V when where U = Y -  X, V = Y, I found the joint pdf of U and V as the following:

f(u,v)= 
\begin{cases} 2e^{-3v+u}, & \in \color{red}{ T=\{(u,v): 0<u<v,v < u+v, v<\infty \}} \\ 
0, & \text{else where}  \end{cases}

My challenge is to find the correct T/range as support for the joint density function of U and V and, then I will use it to find the marginals of each. What is also challenging is finding the support (range) of these marginals as well.

I have looked up for similar questions but it does not seem that I have grasped the method to do so. Is there a more intuitive way to think about it and solve such problems?

Also, I would appreciate more references to read and practice on this particular part of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the original constraint $0<x<y<\infty$ and write it in terms of $u$ and $v$ to get $0 < v-u < v < \infty$. Rewriting these last inequalities gives $0 < u < v < \infty$. This is what you have (note that your $v < u+v$ inequality is redundant with $0 < u$).

To find the support of the marginals, just take the constraints from the joint PDF and ignore the other variable. So $0 < u < \infty$ and $0 < v < \infty$.

Comment: Can you explain further how did you rewrite the initial inequality? And why we should ignore the other variable from the constraints of the joint PDF?

Comment: Substitute $x=v-u$ and $y=v$ into $0<x<y<\infty$. To get the support of the marginal of $U$, just think about what values $u$ can take in the region $0<u<v<\infty$.

Comment: If I have take the integral of f(u,v) over [u,∞] I get f(u)= \begin{cases} 2/3 e^{-2u} , & 0<u<∞ \end{cases} and if I integrate f(u) over [0,∞], I get 1/3 which is incorrect and it should be 1. Or did I miss something here?

Comment: @iAziz I think your original PDF (in $x$ and $y$) is not actually a PDF; it would be if you changed the constraints to $0 < x < \infty$ and $0 < y < \infty$.

Comment: I just realised that my PDF function is not correct and that is why I am getting everything else wrong.